# SSLHandshake exception every time I run the jar file using ftp4j library for FTPST

Tags: java, ssl, jar, ftp, ftps

My `jar` file runs in a Windows Server and connects to another Windows Server using a self-signed certificate through `FTPS`.

Once connected I try to transfer few files back and forth according to the business logic. Every time I try to run the `jar` file I get the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

To rectify this error I have to run the import to keystore commands:

```
cd "%JAVA_HOME%\jre1.8.0_71\bin"

keytool -import -file %certificate path%\<certificate_name>.crt -storepass
changeit -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre1.8.0_71\lib\security\cacerts"
```

And then I get:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias <mykey> already exists
```

After this I am able to run my `jar` file without problem. But each time open a new command window to run my `jar` I have to do this maneuver.

Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance